# Ad Hoc doesn't get downloaded

Tags: ios, plist, ipa, adhoc, ad-hoc-distribution

I want to distribute my iOS app by Ad Hoc.  Since the current version of XCode doesn't create .plist file, so I got one from StackOverflow and filled it as blow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>items</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>assets</key>
                        <array>
                                <dict>
                                        <key>kind</key>
                                        <string>software-package</string>
                                        <key>url</key>
                                        <string>http://hungry.portfolio1000.com/HungryHandongi.ipa</string>
                                </dict>
                        </array>
                        <key>metadata</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                                <string>com.Akadev.HungryHandongi</string>
                                <key>bundle-version</key>
                                <string>1.06</string>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>software</string>
                                <key>title</key>
                                <string>배고픈 한동이</string>
                        </dict>
                </dict>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The url of the .plist file is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tulw9h412me6ayh/HungryHandongi.plist?dl=0

Now I want to let people download the app through the url http://hungry.portfolio1000.com/hungryhandongi.html which is coded like below:

```
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tulw9h412me6ayh/HungryHandongi.plist?dl=0">Download</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body> 
</html>
```

When I open the url with Safari and click 'Download' link, nothing happens.  I want know what I've done wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting this issue for iOS 8.

Yes for Over the air distribution you need to create plist file manually. and you have to change your identifier like

**com.Akadev.HungryHandongi** to **com.Akadev.HungryHandongi.iOS8fix**

Please check below plist , it will help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                     <string>http://www.path.com/build/iphone/some/2015/022015/name/appname.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>url</key>
                     <string>http://www.name.com/build/iphone/EnterpriseTB/2015/022015/some/iTunesArtwork.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>url</key>
                     <string>http://www.some.com/build/iphone/some/2015/022015/some/Icon.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>mobi.somecmp.appname.ios8fix</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>appname 2015</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Note:** For ADHoc Distribution device id should be added into your provisioning profile.